# Black box/White box testing contradictions

Tags: software-design, black-box-testing, white-box-testing

So I already know the difference between white box and black box testing, but **I am looking for fairly straightforward examples of situations where White box says "everything is OK" and Black box testing says "there is a problem here" - as well as vice versa**

These examples would occur in rather popular software products. i.e - Microsoft Windows, Word, or an Equation solver (as shown below)

Something of similar degree to this: (Where black box test fails and white box passes)

> Example: Solving of quadratic equations;
>
> Input data: numeric values of coefficients A, B, and C;
>
> Output data: numeric values of roots X1 and X2

BLACK BOX TEST

> Black-Box testing (environment, users): NO (there is a MISTAKE in
>   internal module, it works incorrectly)
>
> - I’ve been asked to provide numeric values for coefficients A, B and C – I did provide requested values.
> - the internal SQRT module (solving of quadratic equations) did NOT deliver required numeric values of roots X1 and X2.
> - as result, I made a conclusion that there is a mistake inside an internal module.

WHITE BOX TEST

> White-Box testing (an internal module): YES (I work CORRECTLY)
>
> - The input combination of values for A, B and C is illegal because the
>     value the  Discriminant D is negative; therefore, I cannot calculate
>     roots X1 and X2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of the **Exception handling** in the code

Where the Developer can see the **exception** as (The input combination of values for A, B and C is illegal) but failed to capture and display exception to user

as a result Black box test fails, where the User is expects output whereas code throws exception and has to display it, so that Black box tester will correct input and gets required output